# How to avoid compiling imports?

Tags: stylus

I've recently encountered a bit of code using Stylus and I can't seem to figure out how to avoid compiling import files.

In SCSS, I would generally structure things like this:

```
scss/
    _reset.scss
    main.scss
    another.scss
```

And after compiling I'm left with a CSS hierarchy like the following.

```
css/
    main.css
    another.css
```

I first did this (mostly from habbit):

```
styl/
    _reset.styl
    main.styl
    another.styl
```

But after running `stylus styl/ --out css/ --compress` was disappointed to see the output included a `_reset.css` file. This isn't unexpected as Stylus isn't guaranteed to behave the same way, but I can't find any documentation on how to achieve the same thing.

How can I avoid compiling files intended only for importing?

Answer (score 1):

According to this discussion dating back from 2011, this is not *yet* possible through the normal CLI : https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/181

You have a few options to do this task depending of your build system.
If you use `bash` or `zsh` you can use excluding glob for every files starting with a `_`

If you use `gulp`, you can filter the input files taken by `gulp.src` or `gulp-ignore`